# CCLayer setTouchPriority has no effect

Tags: android, ios, touch, cocos2d-x, cclayer

I created a Layer, which has a sole purpose to block ("swallow") touches, and this feature can be turned on and off.
The class is very basic, if it receives the touch it always swallows it:

```
bool BlockingLayer::init(){

    // Super init.
    if ( !CCLayer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    setTouchEnabled(true);
    setTouchMode(kCCTouchesOneByOne);
    setTouchPriority(INT_MAX);

    return true;
}



bool BlockingLayer::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent)
{
    CCLOG("BlockingLayer swallowed touch!");
    return true;
}
```

So by default it has a really bad priority, it receives touches if no other class claimed it. But in the scene where I am using this layer I would like to set it to a different priority when certain events occur:

```
bool MyScene::init(int unitNumber, CCString* path){
    // Super init.
    ...
    _blockingLayer = BlockingLayer::create();
    this->addChild(_blockingLayer);

    return true;
}

bool MyScene::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent){
     _blockingLayer->setTouchPriority(INT_MIN);
     ...
}
```

Now the layer should have the best priority possible, so it should swallow all touches. But it does not, its behaviour does not change.
I see its registerWithTouchDispatcher() called and the m_nTouchPriority changed  correctly. BUT the layer's behaviour is unchanged.

This is on Cocos2D-x 2.2. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I found out that this bug fix caused this new bug: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/issues/752 The last comment shows exactly this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in Cocos2d-x:

see this:

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/5641

Solution:

change in CCTouchDispatcher.cpp
this:

```
void CCTouchDispatcher::addStandardDelegate(CCTouchDelegate *pDelegate, int nPriority)
{    
    CCTouchHandler *pHandler = CCStandardTouchHandler::handlerWithDelegate(pDelegate, nPriority);
    if (! m_bLocked)
    {
        forceAddHandler(pHandler, m_pStandardHandlers);
    }
    else
    {
        /* If pHandler is contained in m_pHandlersToRemove, if so remove it from     m_pHandlersToRemove and return.
         * Refer issue #752(cocos2d-x)
         */
         if (ccCArrayContainsValue(m_pHandlersToRemove, pDelegate))
         {
             ccCArrayRemoveValue(m_pHandlersToRemove, pDelegate);
             return;
          }

        m_pHandlersToAdd->addObject(pHandler);
        m_bToAdd = true;
    }
}
```

and

```
void CCTouchDispatcher::addTargetedDelegate(CCTouchDelegate *pDelegate, int nPriority, bool bSwallowsTouches)
{    
    CCTouchHandler *pHandler = CCTargetedTouchHandler::handlerWithDelegate(pDelegate, nPriority, bSwallowsTouches);
    if (! m_bLocked)
    {
        forceAddHandler(pHandler, m_pTargetedHandlers);
    }
    else
    {
        /* If pHandler is contained in m_pHandlersToRemove, if so remove it from m_pHandlersToRemove and return.
         * Refer issue #752(cocos2d-x)
         */
         if (ccCArrayContainsValue(m_pHandlersToRemove, pDelegate))
          {
              ccCArrayRemoveValue(m_pHandlersToRemove, pDelegate);
              return;
          }

        m_pHandlersToAdd->addObject(pHandler);
        m_bToAdd = true;
    }
}
```

to this:

```
void CCTouchDispatcher::addStandardDelegate(CCTouchDelegate *pDelegate, int nPriority)
{    
    CCTouchHandler *pHandler = CCStandardTouchHandler::handlerWithDelegate(pDelegate, nPriority);
    if (! m_bLocked)
    {
        forceAddHandler(pHandler, m_pStandardHandlers);
    }
    else
    {
        /* If pHandler is contained in m_pHandlersToRemove, if so remove it from m_pHandlersToRemove and return.
         * Refer issue #752(cocos2d-x)
         */
        if (ccCArrayContainsValue(m_pHandlersToRemove, pDelegate))
        {
            CCTouchHandler *pOldHandler = findHandler(pDelegate);
            if (pOldHandler && pOldHandler->getPriority() == nPriority)
            {
                ccCArrayRemoveValue(m_pHandlersToRemove, pDelegate);
                return;
            }
        }

        m_pHandlersToAdd->addObject(pHandler);
        m_bToAdd = true;
    }
}
```

and

```
void CCTouchDispatcher::addTargetedDelegate(CCTouchDelegate *pDelegate, int nPriority, bool bSwallowsTouches)
{    
    CCTouchHandler *pHandler = CCTargetedTouchHandler::handlerWithDelegate(pDelegate, nPriority, bSwallowsTouches);
    if (! m_bLocked)
    {
        forceAddHandler(pHandler, m_pTargetedHandlers);
    }
    else
    {
        /* If pHandler is contained in m_pHandlersToRemove, if so remove it from m_pHandlersToRemove and return.
         * Refer issue #752(cocos2d-x)
         */
        if (ccCArrayContainsValue(m_pHandlersToRemove, pDelegate))
        {
            CCTouchHandler *pOldHandler = findHandler(pDelegate);
            if (pOldHandler && pOldHandler->getPriority() == nPriority)
            {
                ccCArrayRemoveValue(m_pHandlersToRemove, pDelegate);
                return;
            }
        }

        m_pHandlersToAdd->addObject(pHandler);
        m_bToAdd = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addTargetedDelegate() set the third param to true

```
 bool BlockingLayer::init(){

    // Super init.
    if ( !CCLayer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    setTouchEnabled(true);
    setTouchMode(kCCTouchesOneByOne);
    setTouchPriority(INT_MAX);

    return true;
}

void BlockingLayer::onEnter()
{
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, INT_MAX, true);  //<---- Param (target, touchPriority, isSwallowTouches )
    CCNode::onEnter();
}

void BlockingLayer::onExit()
{
     CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->removeDelegate( this );
     CCNode::onExit();
}


bool BlockingLayer::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent)
{
    CCLOG("BlockingLayer swallowed touch!");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you are adding `TargetDelegate` on any layer then you must remove it to function touch properly. You can remove either in `onExit()` or manually call anywhere you need.

Comment: All this happens automatically on CCLayers where Touch is enabled. Their registerWithTouchDispatcher method is automatically called which calls the mentioned line. :) I use your method in non CCLayer classes though. :)